# Cron task to automate Python script

Tags: cron, python

I want to set up a cron task to automate a Python script. For example:
Suppose we have the script in the desktop directory.

```
#set to run at 7 am each day
mkdir url1
cp newspaper.py url1
python newspaper.py URL
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. modify your script so it won't rely on relative paths. You can use `cd` in your script, but `mkdir newdir` will attempt to create that `newdir` in a folder you won't expect. Do `cd /proper/path` first or do `mkdir /proper/path/newdir`, and do not forget that all other file manipulation commands are also could be victims of relative paths.
2. add your script into cron, use `crontab -e` command and a string

```
0 7 * * * /full/path/to/script/script
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a correct shebang, depending on your scripting language.